# High Sierra - Keychain folder takes up a lot of storage

Tags: macos, memory, storage, macos-highsierra

I have a file in
`~Library/Application Support/com.apple.sbd/[UUID]/KeychainV0-tomb/genp.bt3` that takes up 113.88 GB

Any idea what its for, and if it needs to be this big?

Comment: According to this - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7342244 it's your iCloud keychain which has possibly lost sync. Linc Davis is a clever chap on the Apple forums & is usually right - however I just checked my own file & not only is it only 176KB, but it hasn't been modified since 2017 [which is probably around when I got this Mac], so I can't validate his answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. That was just what I was spending the past couple of hours googling for!